# Indexer Schedule

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How often does the repository indexer run? In other words, after a repository is added to the indexer, how long does it usually take for the <> information to be filled?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10989/indexer-schedule/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, repository maintainers should not expect index updates more than once a day.  We regularly prioritize other jobs over the indexer, and the indexer may take anywhere between 5-8 hours depending on how sourceforge and other sites are doing.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2